# Inherit parents function when using ngInclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that uses ngInclude and I would like to call parents ctrl function. This is how I do it now, but it does not work.

```
//MyCtrl
$scope.shareLink = function () {
    // do something
};
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl"> 
    <my-directive></my-directive>  
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="share-link-actions.html">
        <a href="#" ng-click="$parent.$parent.shareLink();">Share</a>
    </script>
</div>

<!-- myDirective --> 
<div class="myDirective1">
    <div ng-include="share-link-actions.html"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

JS

```
directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<a href='#' ng-click='shareLink();'>Share</a>"
    };
});
```

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl"> 
    <my-directive></my-directive>  
</div>
```